# Handle hazelcast instance shutdown while data is being put into IMap through submitKey

Tags: hazelcast, shutdown

I want to handle the scenario that while an entry is being updated into hazelcast, if the shutdown method is called, then it should wait before the data is updated and backed up. 
The documentation states that the shutdown does wait for partitions and backups, but in case a map entry is being updated, does it wait for that too? 
If no, then how can I use the hazelcast to know what write actions are currently in progress through it?
Thanks! 
Raj

Answer (score 1):

Partition operations and backups are all executed by partition threads. A shutdown waits for all queues to flush and all pending operations, including those owned by partition threads, to complete before shutting down the member.